# Is synchronized needed here

Tags: java, synchronization, multithreading

I have a java applet. A class inside that applet is creating a thread to do some work, waiting 30 seconds for that work to complete, if its not completed in 30 secs it sets a Boolean to stop the thread. The wait and Boolean change are in a synchronized block, Is this necessary considering there is no other thread running aside from these 2.

```
    System.out.println("Begin Start Session");
    _sessionThread = new SessionThread();
    _sessionThread.start();

    synchronized (_sessionThread)
    {
        _sessionThread.wait(30000);
        _sessionThread._stopStartSession = true;
    }
```

Why couldn't I just do this instead.

```
    System.out.println("Begin Start Session");
    _sessionThread = new SessionThread();
    _sessionThread.start();

    _sessionThread.wait(30000);
    _sessionThread._stopStartSession = true;
```

SessionThread run method. Invokes a JNI method to call a dll to open a program window.

```
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        startExtraSession();
    } 
    catch (Throwable t)
    {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
        notify();
}


private native void openSessionWindow(String session_file);

private void startExtraSession()
{
    final String method_name = "startExtraSession";

    String title = _sessionInfo._title;
    long hwnd = 0;

    openSessionWindow(_sessionInfo._configFile);

    try
    {
        //Look for a window with the predefined title name...
        while ((hwnd = nativeFindWindow(title)) == 0 && !_stopStartSession)
        {
            Thread.sleep(500);
    }
    }
    catch(Throwable t)
    {
       t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**1. Is the synchronized really needed?**

**2. Is there a better way to accomplish this aside from using threads?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A given thread is required to own a lock on a object to be able to call `wait(long)` on it. This is achieved by using a synchronized block on the said object.

See [J2SE specification](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long)) on using `wait`.

Acquiring a lock/monitor in java can be done in various ways:

- In a `synchronized` (non-static) method, the thread owns a monitor on the object referenced by `this`.
- In a `static synchronized` method, the thread owns a monitor on the `Class<?>` descriptor for the class that defines the said method.
- In a `synchronized(x)` block, the thread owns a monitor on `x`.

That lock will be released if:

- You get outside of the synchronized code block (be it a method, static method, or explicit block).
- You have called `wait()` or one of its variations (and you'll re-acquire it just before the method returns).

Both these two lists may omit specific cases but should cover at least a large portion of the typical use cases.

Comment: If the thread is owned by the class he's calling the synchronized section from, doesn't that fulfill this requirement? It's been a long time since my Java days, so please enlighten me.

Comment: If you're outside of any synchronized method or any synchronized block, you don't own any monitor and hence cannot call `wait`. Let me edit my answer to be a bit clearer on lock/monitor acquisition.

Answer (score 1):

There's a very simple reason that you need `synchronized` to call `wait`

The `synchronized` makes sure that nobody is calling `notify` or `notifyAll` at the same time you're calling `wait`

For example:  Thread 1

```
synchronized( obj )
{
    triggerActionOnThread2();
    obj.wait();
}
```

Thread 2 (triggered by triggerActionOnThread2)

```
    ...
    synchronized( obj )
    {
        obj.notify();
    }
```

If you don't have the synchronized blocks, then the `notify` might happen before (or during) the `wait`, and then the `wait` misses the `notify`, and you can hang Thread 1.

Imagine the above blocks of code without the `synchronized` blocks, and imagine if Thread 2 is executed all the way through the notify before the wait gets called.

BTW, I ask this very question on interviews for Java engineers when the job will involve multithreaded programming.

Comment: It seems like the synchronization is for the express purpose of when there is an exception?

Comment: Not exactly.  The synchronization is to ensure the correct order.  wait/notify is basically a semaphore.  You want to ensure one thread waits first and the other thread notifies second.

Comment: I meant in the example given. But after looking at it again, the notify() is AFTER the try/catch. Thanks for your input (or is it your output?)!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post SessionThread code? You cannot wait if you don't own the lock, so you need synchronized (_sessionThread) to do _sessionThread.wait(30000); Not sure what's with _sessionThread._stopStartSession = true;

Comment: Yeah if the 2nd thread is running longer than 30 secs the while will break when the boolean changes.  Posted the other code as well

Answer (score 0):

If the boolean is the only shared state between the threads, declaring the boolean transient will guarantee that changes to it are seen between the threads as would a synchronization block around access to the boolean.